# Object has values before anything has been assigned to it

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm not sure how to make the question more precise.

[image]

I have this table. As you can see, there is some checkboxes in each row, and the `checked` value is assigned in a multidimensional object with structure as shown below.

[image]

The `checked` values are being loaded from a JSON file, and when you press save it creates a new object that's suppose to have same identical structure but with the updated values and then overwrite the JSON file.

The code:

```
function saveRecruit() {
        var obj = {};
        var specsObj = {};
        var classesObj = {};
        var rowCount = $("#classTable tr").length;
        var columnCount;
        var jsonChar;
        var jsonSpec;
        var jsonSpecRC;
        var jsonString;
        console.log("------ LOGGING FIRST: specsObj ------");
        console.log(specsObj);
        for(x = 1;x<=rowCount;x++)
        {
            jsonChar = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ") td:nth-child(1)").text();
            columnCount = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ")").children().length;

            for(y = 2;y<=columnCount;y++)
            {
                jsonSpec = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ") td:nth-child(" + y + ")").text();
                jsonSpecRC = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ") td:nth-child(" + y + ") input:nth-child(2)")[0].checked;
                console.log("Setting " + jsonSpec + " to " + jsonSpecRC + " in specsObj");
                console.log("X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
                specsObj[jsonSpec] = jsonSpecRC;
            };
            obj[jsonChar] = specsObj;
            console.log(jsonChar + ": specsObj");
            console.log(specsObj);
        };
        console.log("Logging obj");
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(jsonString);

        $("#jsonInput").val(jsonString);
        return false;
    };
```

It checks each row and afterwards assign each column value to that row in two `for` loops. However, here comes the problem that's been bugging me for the last few hours. For some reason, all the `checked` values are being assigned to **each** "tier 1" object as shown in below image. I really don't understand it, as obviously, the druid object should only contain the values for rc, balance, feral, guardian and restoration.

I hope you guys can help me figure this out, and feel free to tell me if I've been unclear about something. Thanks in advance!

[image]

**EDIT:** Forgot to include the stuff related to the title. I'm not sure, but all the values are being assigned before the `for` loops are being run.

```
function saveRecruit() {
        var obj = {};
        var specsObj = {};
        var classesObj = {};
        var rowCount = $("#classTable tr").length;
        var columnCount;
        var jsonChar;
        var jsonSpec;
        var jsonSpecRC;
        var jsonString;
        console.log("------ LOGGING FIRST: specsObj ------");
        console.log(specsObj);
...
```

The variable `specsObj` is being declared and logged before any value has been assigned. You can see the log in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside your loops you keep adding to the `specsObj` without resetting for each row.

Here is your code with an added line to take care of the problem

```
for(x = 1;x<=rowCount;x++)
    {
        jsonChar = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ") td:nth-child(1)").text();
        columnCount = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ")").children().length;

        specsObj = {}; // add this to reset the specsObj for each character

        for(y = 2;y<=columnCount;y++)
        {
            jsonSpec = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ") td:nth-child(" + y + ")").text();
            jsonSpecRC = $("#classTable tr:nth-child(" + x + ") td:nth-child(" + y + ") input:nth-child(2)")[0].checked;
            console.log("Setting " + jsonSpec + " to " + jsonSpecRC + " in specsObj");
            console.log("X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
            specsObj[jsonSpec] = jsonSpecRC;
        };
        obj[jsonChar] = specsObj;
        console.log(jsonChar + ": specsObj");
        console.log(specsObj);
    };
```

Comment: Of course, not sure how I completely overthinked this. However, can you tell me why it logged the filled object before anything was assigned? **Edit:** Also, thanks a lot for the quick answer :) appreciate it

Comment: @StevoHN that is because in chrome it logs the live object, so when you go to the console and open it, it has already been updated with whatever happens in the loops.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the clarification. So I can't really rely on that for troubleshooting. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: not if you are logging the whole object. If you tried logging a specific property you would get `undefined` as expected. Or you could do a deep copy of the object for logging `console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(specsObj)) );`

Comment: I see. However, I just realised, that the script is obviously getting cached, however the JSON object is as well, meaning I need to either force reload the script on the front page where the info is shown, or change the checkboxes to a giant form and store it in a database. Can you recommend either?